# Using Flask-Script with Apache

Tags: apache, flask, flask-script

I'm using Flask-Script. In development, I start my app by calling `./manage.py runserver` and that would make it run on port 5000.

I'm trying to deploy my app with Apache. I can't find the directive that would supply the parameter `runserver` to my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't.  Flask-Script is a convenient way to write management commands.  The `runserver` command simply runs the development server for the app.  In production, you don't want to run the development server.  Instead, you use a WSGI server such as [mod_wsgi](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.org/) or [uwsgi](https://uwsgi.readthedocs.org/) and point it directly at the Flask app object.  Also see the [Flask docs on how to deploy](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/dev/deploying/).